# Automated testing of iOS enterprise deployment

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, jenkins, enterprise

I run the mobile development team at my company and we have an Enterprise app store to distribute the apps to our employees. The store is fed directly from our continuous build server (Jenkins on OS X).

Our biggest problem is that apps that compile and build properly on Jenkins often don't install on the device due to strange validation and license requirements that aren't imposed on dev devices.

Is there a way (preferably Jenkins integrated) to automate the testing of this deployment step i.e. push a built .ipa to a device and see if it installs correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Greg Hughes' *transporter chief* script to install your application from a shell, this script is using the same features as Itunes to install the ipa.

What errors do you get while installing?
I've been running our ad hoc distribution site for alpha and dev builds towards our customers and developers, and it have worked pretty smoothly for the past 12-16 months.

As long as the app is built and signed successfully there haven't been problems with the distribution, although we've had some "false positive" builds where some part of the process borked the app, this have now been pretty much eliminated by monitoring the success of each step and proper clean up before next build.

[Greg Hughes @ github](https://github.com/ghughes/fruitstrap)

Comment: It's strange validation errors like having an Icon.png file in the wrong place, a file with a relative path that doesn't work but doesn't fail the build. I'll check out that script, thanks!

Comment: You can also have a look at my script for OTA distribution for iOS, maybe it can be of any help: https://github.com/sveinungkb/ios-ota-buddy

Comment: nice script, but that's not what I'm looking for. Greg Hughes' script automates this process fully. Thanks though